# Return a new column with column names where date is the same in each row in R

Tags: r

I have a large dataset with several columns with diagnosis dates for several conditions per patient. I would like to return a new column called "same_day" with column names that have same date. Essentially to know which conditions were diagnosed on the same date.

i.e., if the starting data is

```
data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),col1 = as.Date(c("2011-02-01","2020-09-01",NA,"2010-06-01",NA,"2015-02-02")),col2 = as.Date(c("2010-02-01","2018-09-01","2012-03-01",NA,NA,NA)), col3 = as.Date(c("2010-02-01",NA,"2012-03-01","2003-05-01","2000-02-01",NA)),col4=as.Date(c("2011-02-01",NA,"2019-09-10","2014-03-05",NA,"2015-02-02")))
```

```
  ID       col1       col2       col3       col4
1  1 2011-02-01 2010-02-01 2010-02-01 2011-02-01
2  2 2020-09-01 2018-09-01       <NA>       <NA>
3  3       <NA> 2012-03-01 2012-03-01 2019-09-10
4  4 2010-06-01       <NA> 2003-05-01 2014-03-05
5  5       <NA>       <NA> 2000-02-01       <NA>
6  6 2015-02-02       <NA>       <NA> 2015-02-02
```

Then the end result should be:

```
data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),col1 = as.Date(c("2011-02-01","2020-09-01",NA,"2010-06-01",NA,"2015-02-02")),col2 = as.Date(c("2010-02-01","2018-09-01","2012-03-01",NA,NA,NA)), col3 = as.Date(c("2010-02-01",NA,"2012-03-01","2003-05-01","2000-02-01",NA)),col4=as.Date(c("2011-02-01",NA,"2019-09-10","2014-03-05",NA,"2015-02-02")),same_day = c("col1_col4,col2_col3","none","col2_col3","none","none","col1_col4"))
```

```
  ID       col1       col2       col3       col4            same_day
1  1 2011-02-01 2010-02-01 2010-02-01 2011-02-01 col1_col4,col2_col3
2  2 2020-09-01 2018-09-01       <NA>       <NA>                none
3  3       <NA> 2012-03-01 2012-03-01 2019-09-10           col2_col3
4  4 2010-06-01       <NA> 2003-05-01 2014-03-05                none
5  5       <NA>       <NA> 2000-02-01       <NA>                none
6  6 2015-02-02       <NA>       <NA> 2015-02-02           col1_col4
```

Comment: What do you want if `col1 = col4` and `col2 = col3`, but `col1 != col2`?

Comment: If there is such a case, then return col1_col4, col2_col3. So just the pairs of the dates that are the same. Thanks for that

Comment: That significantly complicates the answer, so I would suggest including such a case in your example data if you want it as part of the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible tidyverse approach:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <-
  data.frame(
    ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
    col1 = as.Date(
      c("2011-02-01", "2020-09-01", NA, "2010-06-01", NA, "2015-02-02")
    ),
    col2 = as.Date(c(
      "2010-02-01", "2018-09-01", "2012-03-01", NA, NA, NA
    )),
    col3 = as.Date(
      c("2010-02-01", NA, "2012-03-01", "2003-05-01", "2000-02-01", NA)
    ),
    col4 = as.Date(
      c("2011-02-01", NA, "2019-09-10", "2014-03-05", NA, "2015-02-02")
    )
  )

# with lag/lead
df |> 
  pivot_longer(-ID, values_to = "date") |> 
  arrange(ID, date) |> 
  mutate(same_day = if_else(date == lag(date) | date == lead(date), name, NA), .by = ID) |> 
  mutate(same_day = str_flatten(same_day, collapse = "_"), .by = c(ID, date)) |> 
  arrange(ID, name) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = date) |> 
  reframe(across(everything(), \(x) str_flatten(x, collapse = " ", na.rm = T)), .by = ID) |> 
  mutate(same_day = str_squish(same_day))
#> # A tibble: 6 × 6
#>      ID same_day              col1         col2         col3         col4       
#>   <dbl> <chr>                 <chr>        <chr>        <chr>        <chr>      
#> 1     1 "col1_col4 col2_col3" "2011-02-01" "2010-02-01" "2010-02-01" "2011-02-0…
#> 2     2 ""                    "2020-09-01" "2018-09-01" ""           ""         
#> 3     3 "col2_col3"           ""           "2012-03-01" "2012-03-01" "2019-09-1…
#> 4     4 ""                    "2010-06-01" ""           "2003-05-01" "2014-03-0…
#> 5     5 ""                    ""           ""           "2000-02-01" ""         
#> 6     6 "col1_col4"           "2015-02-02" ""           ""           "2015-02-0…

# n()
df |> 
  pivot_longer(-ID, values_to = "date") |> 
  arrange(ID, date) |> 
  mutate(same_day = if_else(n() > 1 & !is.na(date), str_flatten(name, collapse = "_"), NA), .by = c(ID, date)) |> 
  arrange(ID, name) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = date) |> 
  reframe(across(everything(), \(x) str_flatten(x, collapse = " ", na.rm = T)), .by = ID) |> 
  mutate(same_day = str_squish(same_day))
#> # A tibble: 6 × 6
#>      ID same_day              col1         col2         col3         col4       
#>   <dbl> <chr>                 <chr>        <chr>        <chr>        <chr>      
#> 1     1 "col1_col4 col2_col3" "2011-02-01" "2010-02-01" "2010-02-01" "2011-02-0…
#> 2     2 ""                    "2020-09-01" "2018-09-01" ""           ""         
#> 3     3 "col2_col3"           ""           "2012-03-01" "2012-03-01" "2019-09-1…
#> 4     4 ""                    "2010-06-01" ""           "2003-05-01" "2014-03-0…
#> 5     5 ""                    ""           ""           "2000-02-01" ""         
#> 6     6 "col1_col4"           "2015-02-02" ""           ""           "2015-02-0…
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-07 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Interesting approach. The `date == lag(date) | date == lead(date)` feels a little messy, there might be a cleaner approach if you group by both ID and date. Grouping by date, you wouldn't have to check for equality, you could just have `ifelse(n() == 1), "none", ...)`

Comment: Huge thanks for this solution. It takes a while on my over 2 million rows of data but returns the column I want

Answer (score 2):

Per the comments, here is modified data where row 6 includes the `col1==col4, col2==col3, col1!=col2` situation.

```r
dat <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), col1 = structure(c(15006, 18506, NA, 14761, NA, 16468), class = "Date"), col2 = structure(c(14641, 17775, 15400, NA, NA, 15006), class = "Date"), col3 = structure(c(10471, NA, 15400, 12173, 10988, 15006), class = "Date"), col4 = structure(c(15006, NA, 18149, 16134, NA, 16468), class = "Date")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
dat
#   ID       col1       col2       col3       col4
# 1  1 2011-02-01 2010-02-01 1998-09-02 2011-02-01
# 2  2 2020-09-01 2018-09-01       <NA>       <NA>
# 3  3       <NA> 2012-03-01 2012-03-01 2019-09-10
# 4  4 2010-06-01       <NA> 2003-05-01 2014-03-05
# 5  5       <NA>       <NA> 2000-02-01       <NA>
# 6  6 2015-02-02 2011-02-01 2011-02-01 2015-02-02
```

With this, we can do what you want this way:

```r
out <- asplit(dat, 1) |>
  sapply(function(x) {
    tb <- split(names(x), x)
    paste(sapply(tb[lengths(tb) > 1], paste, collapse="_"), collapse = ",")
  })
out
# [1] "col1_col4"           ""                    "col2_col3"           ""                    ""                    "col2_col3,col1_col4"
```

I suggest either empty strings `""` or `NA` for the nothing-found values, but you can also use the literal `"none"` if needed:

```r
replace(out, !nzchar(out), NA)
# [1] "col1_col4"           NA                    "col2_col3"           NA                    NA                    "col2_col3,col1_col4"
replace(out, !nzchar(out), "none")
# [1] "col1_col4"           "none"                "col2_col3"           "none"                "none"                "col2_col3,col1_col4"
```

---

With your updated data:

```r
dat2 <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), col1 = structure(c(15006, 18506, NA, 14761, NA, 16468), class = "Date"), col2 = structure(c(14641, 17775, 15400, NA, NA, NA), class = "Date"), col3 = structure(c(14641, NA, 15400, 12173, 10988, NA), class = "Date"), col4 = structure(c(15006, NA, 18149, 16134, NA, 16468), class = "Date")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
out2 <- asplit(dat2, 1) |>
  sapply(function(x) {
    tb <- split(names(x), x)
    paste(sapply(tb[lengths(tb) > 1], paste, collapse="_"), collapse = ",")
  })
out2
# [1] "col2_col3,col1_col4" ""                    "col2_col3"           ""                    ""                    "col1_col4"
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for this, this gives me exactly what i want, is there a tidyverse solution as well that adds the new column to the dataset? Huge thanks

Comment: Hmmm, this is a lot like the answer I've been working on, just shorter, cleaner, and posted sooner.

Comment: Tidy packages do really well with columns of data; they can do row-wise operations as well, but it becomes a bit more onerous to work on both row-wise data and the names of each of the columns. Is it possible? Likely. Hastily, just wrap the `asplit(..) |> sapply(..)` in a user-defined function, then call it as `mutate(quux = newfun(pick(col1:col4)))` and it should work fine. Otherwise, I know of no elegant way in dplyr/tidyr to work on this without a pivoting/calc/summarize/join process (that Carl just posted :-), that is perhaps more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: @GregorThomas, see my approach in tidyverse style, in one pipeline only without using `rowwise()`

Answer (score 0):

One more possible approach

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-ID) %>% 
  drop_na() %>% 
  filter(n() > 1, .by = c(ID, value)) %>% 
  summarise(same_day = paste0(name, collapse = "_"), .by = c(ID, value)) %>% 
  summarise(same_day = paste0(same_day, collapse = ","), .by = ID) %>% 
  left_join(df, .,
             by = join_by(ID)) %>% 
  replace_na(list(same_day = "none"))
#>   ID       col1       col2       col3       col4            same_day
#> 1  1 2011-02-01 2010-02-01 2010-02-01 2011-02-01 col1_col4,col2_col3
#> 2  2 2020-09-01 2018-09-01       <NA>       <NA>                none
#> 3  3       <NA> 2012-03-01 2012-03-01 2019-09-10           col2_col3
#> 4  4 2010-06-01       <NA> 2003-05-01 2014-03-05                none
#> 5  5       <NA>       <NA> 2000-02-01       <NA>                none
#> 6  6 2015-02-02       <NA>       <NA> 2015-02-02           col1_col4
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>